# Having trouble viewing saved query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have recently started working with Bigquery. I can not find my saved query as described in the official documentation. Can someone please help on how to retreive my saved query?

Official documentation talks about moving to explorer and then look for saved query nodes. I didnt get any such nodes in the panel.

Comment: That question is not related to coding, and the answer can easily be found using documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your saved queries are under the project in the `BigQuery` console :

[image]

Comment: If it's the case, can you mark the answer as solved please ?

Comment: Yes thank you. I am a newbie here and didnt know about the same. Apologies.!